# LTI 1.3 SDK in Visual studio or nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sdk, nuget, nuget-package, lti

Can anyone suggest me which package/SDK/nuget package can be used for LTI 1.3 in visual studio.I am using visual studio 2015 but I din't found any SDK/packages/nuget package for integrating LTI 1.3(IMS Global).

I found one link which support **till LTI 1.2 version**.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/LtiLibrary.Core/
hence I need some different link for LTI 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

> LTI 1.3 SDK in Visual studio or nuget package

I can only find such nuget package called [LtiAdvantage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LtiAdvantage/0.1.1-alpha.0). It is a pre-release version and was released recently.

This package is used for **Net Core** and has the feature of `LTI 1.3`. See [this github link](https://github.com/LtiLibrary/LtiAdvantage/tree/master/src/LtiAdvantage) and [those](https://github.com/andyfmiller/LtiAdvantagePlatform). It seems that the Team has added `LTI 1.3` feature on **Net Core** projects so far.

**However**, **VS2015** does not support this nuget package and **Net Core**.

**If** you still want this feature on VS2015, I am afraid that you cannot get what you want. **VS2015** is too old to use this new release nuegt package and Net Core.

**As a suggestion,**

you could download [VS2019 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) or VS2017 Community and then create a **Net Core** project to use that nuget package.

**Also**, remember to click `Include prerelease` option.

[image]

===============================

**Update**

**Actually**, this is the only one which has the feature `LTI 1.3`. However, it is only for net core projects and `VS2017+` and may not work well with your VS2015. And the team is currently working hard to develop the nuget package for `LTI 1.3`, which is not very complete. It may not be available to all project types including `Net Framework`. If you still want to use this package under the `Net Framework` project in **VS2015** , You should need to `contact the author` to feedback your request.

Comment: Actually, this is the only one which has the feature `LTI 1.3`. However, it is only for net core projects and `VS2017+` and may not work well with your VS2015. And the team is currently working hard to develop the nuget package for LTI 1.3, which is not very complete. It may not be available to all project types including net framework. If you still want to use this package in the net framework project in vs2015 , You should need to contact the author to feedback your request.