# LTI 1.3 Integration with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lti

I need to integrate my **ASP.NET MVC 5** web application(this is not a .Net core project) with LTI 1.3 version. Few examples found was developed with .Net Core projects. The **LTI 1.3** Library in  VS Nuget package manager is in Pre-release. Is it possible to integrate with ASP.NET MVC project?  If anyone has built similar kind of solutions, Please provide you inputs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576289/lti-1-3-sdk-in-visual-studio-or-nuget-package

Comment: @Chetan - Thanks for your inputs. Could you please provide some samples for integrating with MVC application?

Comment: Hi @jeenap 
Did you implement integration with LMS voa LTI 1.3?
I have questions

Comment: we put that implementation on old